# ERROR 1045 (28000) mysql user@some_name

Tags: mysql

Yeah, I know, this error again...

The difference is the ending part of the error: user@**some_name**.

All the hits on SO and Google were for user@hostname or user@localhost or user@ip. This MySQL error on the client is coming back with **some_name**. The connection is made successfully from the client to the server if I update the user from user@ip to user@% in the mysql.user table. This indicates there is no firewall, password, or other issue, its simply a MySQL configuration problem. So I need to have MySQL use the IP not this 'some_name' value (which I'd be REALLY interested in knowing where its coming from).

As a side note, it is not acceptable to use wildcards where I work, we are not allowed to use wildcards, so I cannot use that as the answer.

I looked around my server, **some_name** does not exist in /etc/hosts or /etc/sysconfig/network nor is it returned by a 'hostname' CLI execution. I need to determine where it got this name and why mysql is not using the IP (and fix it) so that I can update the mysql.users table to reflect the user@ip so that the connection can be made.

Client Setup:
RHEL 6.5 
MySQL Client 5.1.73

Server 
RHEL 6.5
MySQL Server 5.1.73

Thanks!
SK

Comment: Have you done a reverse DNS lookup from the MySQL server to the client IP? I bet, you'll get *some_name*

Comment: Interesting. I found this in the servernames /etc/host (I was looking in the clients /etc/host): client_ip some_name So how do I fix this problem so that I can have 'user'@'ip' work in the mysql.user table, or should I just enter in 'user'@'some_name'?

Comment: If this information is **wrong**, the way to deal with it is to remove it from `/etc/hosts`. In a second round, you will have to deal with DNS.

Comment: That was basically the solution though, that the server had the client in its /etc/host and MySQL was doing reverse lookups. I put in the my.cnf an entry to "skip-name-resolve" and now the connections are working based on the IP in the mysql.users table. thanks again!

Comment: You should answer yourself and mention `skip-name-resolve` to make the value of the research accessible for the next user with the same or a similar problem

Comment: Hey ER, noob question, how do i do that?

Comment: Looks like you sorted it out!

Comment: Yeah, brain fart. Thanks though, hopefully helps someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the MySQL client connected to the MySQL server, I did not know that the MySQL Server was using the /etc/host file to do a reverse lookup.  In that file, I had an alias *'some_name' 'ip'* line item listed (for shortcuts to ping and such). Thus, MySQL Server went to the mysql.user table and looked for *'username'@'some_name'*, it did not find it, and thus threw the error: **ERROR 1045 (28000) mysql user@some_name**. The mysql.user table only had an entry for *'username'@'client_ip'*.

To alleviate the problem, I configured MySQL server, using /etc/my.cnf, to not use reverse lookups by adding a line under the mysqld:

```
[mysqld]
skip-name-resolve
```

After restarting MySQL server, the client connection worked since the Server was now using the *'username@client_ip'* entry for authorization.